# codeigniter sound notification system

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

here is notification method

```
public function activetask() {
              $notification['ReceiverID']=$this->input->post('user_reciver_id');
              $notification['SenderID']=$this->input->post('createdby');
              $notification['Status']=$this->input->post('task');
              $notification['AppID']=$this->input->post('App_id'); 
              $notification['TaskID']=$this->input->post('PhaseID');
              $notification['CreatedDate']=date('D M Y h:i');
              $this->Mapps->notification($notification);

            if($this->input->post('user_reciver_id')==$this->session->userdata('id')){

echo '<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>';
             }
```

here ajax function call on click event

```
function active(task,user_reciver_id,createdby,Task_id,App_id,PhaseID){
     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url:  '<?php echo base_url();?>users/activetask',
      cache: false,       
      data: {task: task,Task_id:Task_id,App_id:App_id,PhaseID:PhaseID,user_reciver_id:user_reciver_id,createdby:createdby},
      success: function(response){ 
          location.reload();
      }
   });
  }
```

it does not work for me where is problem
how to solve it

i send some detail  one user to other 
if receiver user is login then listen notification sound

Comment: What's your actual question and precise problem? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: query running correctly but sound does not executed

Comment: i want some detail send one user to other user when one user receive message then execute a sound

Comment: Sorry, that's a broad question and we'd need to see more of your code. Try to be very specific in your question. That way, people will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the echo reponse to some element.

First, Create an element in the html.

```
<div id="audios" style="display:none;">We are audios!</div>
```

Then, get the response in the ajax and append it to #audios before reload the window.

```
     $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url:  '<?php echo base_url();?>users/activetask',
          cache: false,       
          data: {task: task,Task_id:Task_id,App_id:App_id,PhaseID:PhaseID,user_reciver_id:user_reciver_id,createdby:createdby},
          success: function(response){ 
              var audio_html = response;
              $('#audios').append(audio_html);
              location.reload();
          }
      });
```